# Optics of convex mirrors

Tags: physics, reflection

I recently got in an argument with a friend while I was driving. When I moved to a different lane, I did not turn my head to check for any vehicles in my blind spot. Instead, how I checked was by leaning toward the rightmost region of the drivers wheel, looking into the left side mirror to see the field that is normally the blind spot. I've been doing this for several years, I imagine if I was wrong then surely I'd have gotten in an accident by now.

My friend, however, refuses to believe that works. He thinks the blind spot remains fixed no matter where the observer (driver) looks at the mirror or that at least it is not safe/effective as turning your head to look into your blind spot.

I understand mirrors in vehicles are convex mirrors, they slightly bulge out to increase the field of view for the observer (which is why objects appear closer in the mirror and why there is slight distortion). And I know as light hits the mirror, the mirror reflects it back outward. What I'm struggling with is how to explain that the position of the observer changes the blindspot.

How do I make my case mathematically?

Comment: If you're changing to the lane on the left and you lean towards the left mirror, then this will actually make the blind spot *bigger*. If you lean away from the left mirror, then your blind spot will shrink. However, I doubt that you'll be able to safely lean to the point where a car cannot hide in your blind spot. As for why you haven't had an accident, there are many other ways that our minds ensure that there isn't a car next to us (actively scanning for cars around us before they enter the blind spot, visual and audio cues, etc). Also defensive drivers stay out of blind spots, if possible.

Comment: I worded it incorrectly. I don't literally lean **toward** the left mirror, but I lean toward the rightmost region of my wheel. Also, my side mirrors are already adjusted such that my vehicle itself is not in view (which goes against the way mirrors are typically adjusted). That way, the blind spot rotates out further. By the time another vehicle reaches the side mirrors blindspot, they are already visible to my peripheral vision.

Comment: Sure, and that's a very sensible way to orient your mirrors. I think, if possible, you should include a rough diagram of where you are leaning. As it stands, I still have no idea on which side of the road you drive, which could be significant in figuring out whether the left mirror is close to or further away from you.

Comment: Which is the side of the driver, left or right?  UK, HK and Japan are on the right.  US and China are on the left.